# How to fix Failed installation Data Quality Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-quality-services

I want to install Data Quality Server In existing Instance SQL Server. After entered Master key I'm getting error like in below log messages

My OS 
Windows 2012 R2 Standard and SQL Server 2012

```
[8/12/2019 11:58:39 PM] Executing action: Create data quality schema.
[8/12/2019 11:58:39 PM] Script: 'recreate_schema.bat WINDMPSMLMCJBK\SQL2012 DQS SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
[8/12/2019 11:58:39 PM] Failed to create script process.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.Ssdqs.DqsInstaller.Logic.Actions.ScriptExecuterAction.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
[8/12/2019 11:58:39 PM] Action 'Create data quality schema' finished with errors, aborting installation.
```

How to fix the the error? thanks before